# different behaviour of program

Tags: c, scanf

Here is a small program in C.
I want to get user input in a while loop and I also want to take white space in line so I used `scanf("%[^\n]s",name);` but it gives a different output. It's stuck in the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    do
    {
    char name[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    }while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
adAD A SAF A SA FA
```

I want to take input from user with white spaces inside using a while loop.

Comment: There must be tons of (working) examples out there... You must add some means of breaking out of the while loop, like a break when something happens or a different while condition, that actually evaluates some variable.

Comment: Don't for the love of God use scanf!

Comment: You provided the program's output, but what is your input to the program? Which OS is the program running on?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char name[20];
    while(gets(name))
    {
       printf("%s\n", name);
    }
return 0;
```

}

If you want to break the loop of taking input then you have two option AFAIK:
1. If you are in Windows Press CTRL+Z.
2. If you are in Linux Press CTRL+D.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for return value of `scanf` function and decide to `break` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code dt may solve ur prblm although you should consider including some check condition to break from the do while loop. Hope it works

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
char name[20];
  do
  {
   gets(name);
   puts(name);
  }while (1);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `fflush(stdin)` after scanf
Note: fflush on stdin is highly platform specific, but generally works in platforms where you run into this issue

Answer (score -1):

You can use gets() to replace scanf(), like:
    #include

```
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    do
    {
    char name[20];
    //scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
    gets(name);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    }while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

But the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

Comment: -1 for suggesting `gets()`, even though you say it's dangerous and should not be used.